# Firefox Sync's history limit

Tags: firefox, sync, history

I just performed a clean install of my Linux distribution's upgraded version. I signed in to Firefox account and started sync. While browsing my library, I found history items from my old Firefox profile. But what surprised me a lot was browsing history as old as 6 months..!! I know that Firefox Sync deletes history older than 2 months and Sync clients can't see it again. Also, Sync clients cannot upload data older than 30 days. So retention of 6 months of browsing history is not possible.

So, how was that happened ? Has Mozilla changed some policy to extend storage limit for history ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in the Firefox Support article
[History while syncing - it has got only 2 months, why is that?!](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1278903)

> The size of how much Browsing History is saved on Sync is dependent upon a number of variables; the ultimate size would be the **amount of data**, not "calendar time". Bookmarks data storage rarely is an issue; never seen an exact "count" mentioned but anecdotally speaking my guess is well into the tens of thousands for desktop / laptop Firefox versions.

Apparently, storing your 6 months of history did not exceed the
generous data size allocated to you by Firefox Sync.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But if it depends on many variables and the actual storage quota, why did they always said the 60 days limit ? Are they talking about gaps between two syncs must not be greater than 60 days ?

Comment: I think that the 60 days limit is what they do when truncating your history. It will probably only be evoked for trimming your history when its size becomes excessive.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc for your help.